# VASCO Digital Certificate

Tags: java, security, certificate, digital-certificate, pkcs#11

How to read vasco digital certificate.

I am using in config file following

```
name="VASCO DP CertiID PKCS#11 V2.20"
library="C:\Program Files\VASCO\DIGIPASS CertiID\VdsPKCS1132.dll"
```

I am getting this error:

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: KeyStore instantiation failed
    at java.security.KeyStore$Builder$2.getKeyStore(Unknown Source)
    at eTokenApplet.initializeCard(eTokenApplet.java:417)
    at eTokenApplet.getCertificates(eTokenApplet.java:1952)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.JSInvoke.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.JSClassLoader.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MethodInfo.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MemberBundle.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$DefaultInvocationDelegate.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.doObjectOp(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyStore$Builder$2$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: PKCS11 for provider SunPKCS11-VASCO DP CertiID PKCS#11 V2.20
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you passing `Provider` instance with `KeyStore.getInstance` method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the -Djava.library.path= so java can find your dll?